# How do I run a simple project of Selenium web driver with c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn Selenium Web driver with c# and I have created a simple project by using code as mentioned in the image

[image]

And have already add the references, that use in for selenium, but when I am try to run this piece of code. I am getting error as mentioned below

[image]

Kindly let me know, how do I run this piece of code, waiting for reply

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'Test Explorer' view to run tests. It is shown on the left side on your screenshot.

Note that using the green 'Start' button in the tool bar only works for projects that create an exectuable program. It does not work for unit testing projects or library projects.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the file path of the drivers in your environmental variables. Alternatively, you can specify its location when creating an instance of a webdriver, or set the environment variable in your code.

You can download the driver for firefox:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

For Firefox:

```
// Gecko driver is extracted to "C:\GeckoDriverLocation\geckodriver.exe"
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", @"C:\GeckoDriverLocation\");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Driver for chrome: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

For Chrome:

```
//e.g. Chrome driver location is in C:\ChromeDriverLocation\chromedriver.exe
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeWebDriverLocation\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Piece of code for firefox driver is not working for me, still i am getting error

Comment: @user88 Does the code for chrome driver work for you?
Anyhow, I've removed windows from my laptop and will need to set up a VM - well I'd prefer to see if the same thing works with .NET core on Linux, I'll post back my results some other time - maybe on the weekends or next week. 

In the meantime, update your post with your changed code and any new errors/problems you're getting. Using git on github or bitbucket would be nice for showing what you've done so far. Someone else might be able to answer it earlier than I would.

Comment: So using a copy of Windows 10 for Edge testing, I was able to install VS community edition and get my tests running. There were some issues with selenium detecting firefox 64-bit executable, but this can be solved by setting the environment variable like mentioned in my previous posts. I've read Gecki's post tried what he suggested, and found out that using the green start button creates the same error message. I guess my experience with IDEs have always made me run programs/tests by right-clicking in code for tests or main and executing what I want from there, so I don't run into issues.